# how to fetch data (numbers) in double format from Firestore and multiply them in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

So I'm trying to fetch numbers from a specific document and place them in double format and multiply or add the values to each other but first, I need to retrieve them from firestore.
[my data on firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7469.png)
For example:

```html
double com ;
double km;
double minute;
double base ;

double total price = com + km + minute + base ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will, the code will depend on what are the data types of these values on the cloud..
assuming they are already saved as double

```
 final _fireStore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
 double base ;
 double com;
 double km ;
 double minute ;

 await _fireStore
          .collection('prices')
          .doc(userID)
          .get()
          .then((DocumentSnapshot snapShot) {
        if (snapShot.exists) {
            base = snapShot.data()['base'];
            com= snapShot.data()['com'];
            km= snapShot.data()['km'];
            minute= snapShot.data()['minute'];
            print('Done Fitching Data From FireStore');
            print(base);
        }
      });
```

if they are stored as Strings then you will define them as strings at the first 5 lines then you will use

```
double.parse(com);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use .toDouble(); or double.parse();

Comment: sorry but can you explain more ? 
because i'm still learning